# Python boto3 create rds instance from snapshot with backup disabled

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, boto3

I am attempting to create an RDS instance from a production snapshot, which is working fine with boto3. But, I want to create the RDS instance with backups disabled to reduce the time, rather than creating the instance then modifying to disable them after the create. Is there a way to do this in the create process or is it restricted to modify after creation?

```
response = source.restore_db_instance_from_db_snapshot(
        DBInstanceIdentifier=snap_id, 
        DBSnapshotIdentifier=source_snap,
        DBInstanceClass=db_instance_class, 
        DBSubnetGroupName=db_subnet, 
        MultiAZ=False, 
        PubliclyAccessible=True
    )
    print(response)
```

Comment: *"I want to create the RDS instance with backups disabled to reduce the time."*  How does this reduce the time?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot There are various configs which may only be modified via subsequent calls to `modify_db_instance()`. One may have to wait until the database is out of `backing-up` status in order to proceed with the `modify_db_instance` call, depending on what you're doing. The `backing-up` status can slow the entire process down considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is noparameter for [restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/restore-db-instance-from-db-snapshot.html) to change the backup period.

The [RestoreDBClusterFromSnapshot documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_RestoreDBClusterFromSnapshot.html) shows the `BackupRetentionPeriod` as an **Output**, but not an Input. It appears to use the same value as the cluster when the Snapshot was made.